# cannot omit right margin in gnuplot

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I have a plot and want to omit the white margins around the plot but the rmargin doesn't influence the plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB7aB.png)

below is the gnuplot code:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color eps dashed dashlength 2.0 linewidth 1.0 butt noclip

set size square

set output "CMeshIndep.eps"

set key at 2,3
set key font "Times-Bold,20" samplen 10 spacing 3

set tmargin at screen 0.95
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin 1

#set tmargin 0.75
#set bmargin 3.5
#set lmargin 1
#set rmargin 0.25



#set border
set border
set tics nomirror
set xtics font "Times-Bold,20"
set ytics font "Times-Bold,20"

#    EOF
```

So any opinions on how to remove the right blank margin, I need to keep the plot squared, but not the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the canvas size in the `set terminal` option.

If you want to have 10% margin on the left and bottom, and 5% on the right and top, then your canvas is also square, so you can simply add `size 5cm,5cm` e.g. to the `set terminal` line.